# Install legacy NVIDIA drivers side-by-side with the latest one

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, graphics, gpu-driver

I have two Tesla P40 (Pascal) and one GeForce GT 710 (Kepler) installed on my Dell R720 home lab. I installed the latest Nvidia driver from `ubuntu-drivers` (which only detects Tesla P40 and installed `nvidia-driver-535`). On boot, I got the following error in `dmesg`:

```
NVRM: The NVIDIA GeForce GT 710 GPU installed in this system is
NVRM:  supported through the NVIDIA 470.xx Legacy drivers. Please
NVRM:  visit http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html for more
NVRM:  information.  The 535.54.03 NVIDIA driver will ignore
NVRM:  this GPU.  Continuing probe...
```

Of course, I can switch to the 470.xx Legacy drivers for compatibility with the EOF'ed GeForce GT 710 GPU, but that means losing access to compatibility with recent CUDA versions and other new features. Can I install the legacy driver side-by-side with the latest one, probably by installing it under a different name or through some other hacks, so that I can have the best of both worlds?